# Estimation of a sum involving multiplicative character

Tags: group-theory, summation, fourier-transform

Let $p$ be a prime, $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, and

$$ \chi_r(t)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i r \,\,ind_g t}{p-1}\right), r = 0, ..., p-2 $$

is a multiplicative character modulo $p$ with respect to $r$.

I have a set $ A \subseteq F^*_p $ and a Fourier transform $\hat{\mathbb{1}}_A $ of its indicator function, and I want to estimate the sum below for a fixed $r$. I have an estimation (basically, $(p-1)|A|$ comes from estimating the Fourier transform and $p-1$ is because of the multiplicative character):

$$ \bigg| \sum_{x\in (Z/pZ)^\times} \hat{\mathbb{1}}_A(x)^2 \chi_r(x)^2 \bigg| \le (p- 1) |A| \cdot (p-1) = (p-1)^2 |A|$$

I *think* it's possible to have a better estimate, namely

$$\bigg| \sum_{x\in (Z/pZ)^\times} \hat{\mathbb{1}}_A(x)^2 \chi_r(x)^2 \bigg| \le (p-1) \cdot \max_{x}|\mathbb{1}_A(x)^2| = (p-1)|A|^2$$

But I'm not sure whether those are correct, or are there any better obvious estimates that I'm missing?

Comment: Since $1\chi_r(x)|\le1$, one has the trivial bound $\big| \sum_{x\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times} \Bbb 1_A(x)^2 \chi_r(x)^2 \big| \le \sum_{x\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times} \big| \Bbb 1_A(x)^2 \big| = \#A$, which is superior to both bounds in the OP.

Comment: @GregMartin: I apologize, the sum contains the Fourier transform of the indicator function, rather than the indicator function itself...

Comment: Gotcha. I think you can get $\#A\cdot p$ (when $r\ne0$) by using Parseval's identity and the fact that the Fourier transform of $\chi_r$ is a Gauss sum.